# Good Templating engine to be used with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

what are the good alternatives to jquery.tmpl now that jquery team has halted it development. It will now be coordinated by the jQuery UI team, as it will be a dependency of the upcoming jQuery UI Grid. But since grid is still far away in future which engine can i use. My backed is Cakephp

http://blog.jquery.it/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/

PS: MOst questions on this topic are outdated hence i asked this question. So as of 2011 which one should i go for.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788611/what-javascript-template-engines-you-recommend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most commonly-used Javascript templating engines is [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/).

A simpler alternative is contained as part of [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/).

You could also look at :

- [John Resig's Micro Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)
- [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure/) (quite different than other templating solutions...)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is the best

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this question in 2017, it looks like **JsRender** and **JsViews** have emerged as the current *official* implementation of templating within the jQuery ecosystem (whilst not necessarily requiring jQuery):

> JsRender is a light-weight but powerful templating engine, highly extensible, and optimized for high-performance rendering, without DOM dependency. It is designed for use in the browser or on Node.js, with or without jQuery.
>
> JsRender and JsViews together provide the next-generation implementation of the official jQuery plugins JQuery Templates, and JQuery Data Link -- and supersede those libraries.
>
> - *[JsRender GitHub Readme](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender#jsrender-best-of-breed-templating)*

Official Site: http://www.jsviews.com/

GitHub (JsRender): https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

GitHub (JsViews): https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews