# Best practices for component based design using only html and javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I've decided to try and make a web application where the client is only html and javascript/jquery and I will fetch the data from a json service.

I come from the land of web forms and is now learning and loving mvc and here we have master pages and components like user controls and partial views etc, which enables us to re-use components and structure our code.

How do I do this when I'm using only html and javascript?

I've seen that jquery has the method `load()` which loads data from the server. Is this the best approach to achieve what I want? Or is it something out there that I have missed?

Comment: Did you Google JavaScript MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather big and subjective question.

If you plan to consume your data using JSON the method, what you'd probably want to use is [getJSON()](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.getJSON) which is a wrapper of the more flexible `ajax()`.

Then you'll probably need a [templating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788611/what-javascript-template-engines-you-recommend), to avoid creating and injecting html using javascript (it can become a real mess for every task which is a bit more complex than the trivial ones).

Regarding your application structure you might consider patterns such as MVC, MVP or [MVVM](http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvvm-a-guide-for-javascript-developers/). There are [several good libraries](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/) that allow you to leverage these patterns, but personally I'd recommend to start to play without frameworks, and switch to one of them only when you feel a real need for it, and you grasp at least some basic concepts.

Good luck :)

Comment: I've started to look into your suggestions. What I feel is lacking is some sort of "user controlish" solution for html files. Can I somehow avoid putting all html in one file, but rather compose the file of several html files?