# How to construct HTML template and add to DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand that we can use:

```
var ele = "<div></div>";
$('body').append(ele);
```

However this is not as flexible as plain HTML, as all HTML is quoted...

I saw jQuery-templ so that we can use:

```
<script id='tmpl' type='text/html'>
    <div>test</div>
</script>
<script>
    $.tmpl('#tmpl').appendTo('body');
</script>
```

This is good, but this project is not continuing any more (though this is so useful!)

Is there anything similar to that?

Comment: I have a question why this type of code is not flexible as plain html?
`var ele = "<div></div>";
$('body').append(ele);`

Comment: @Sarfaraz Because the template div can be really long, and the quotes has to continue for many lines. Sometimes you have "<div style='background-image:url(\"path\")'>" so you need to escape the inner level of quotes..

Comment: you dont want to use type="text/html" you should use type="text/template" and then use $('#tmpl').html()

Comment: `<script id='tmpl' type='text/html'>
    <div>test</div>
</script>
<script>
    $.tmpl('tmpl').appendTo('body');
</script>`
I've tried this but this is not working can you please explain

Comment: @Sarfaraz it should be '#tmpl'. I missed a sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very light weight underscore library has a [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template%20template) function. This also allows you to use erb style `<%` `%>` to inline javascript code.

Also John Resig (jQuery creator) wrote a [micro templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) function you can drop into your code without calling a library.

Answer (score 2):

you want some thing template engine.  then here are the list.

1. KnockOutJS  [KnockOut JS](http://knockoutjs.com/)
2. HandlerBar [HandleBar JS](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
3. Mustache [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

or alternativiely you can choose your own template engine based on your requirement. [Template Chooser](http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/)
or even from this link [Template chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788611/what-javascript-template-engines-you-recommend)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without using any library (pure JS) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/hMwNV/))

```
var list = [
        'item1',
        'item2',
        'item3'
    ],
    tmpl = '<li>{item}</li>',
    i, t = '';

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    t += tmpl.replace(/\{item\}/g, list[i]);
}
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + t + '</ul>';
```