# How to make make this code clearer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sorry if it is a simple problem for you.But i am really struggling with this problem

In our application we have plenty of ajax calls in each and every page. We are using jQuery ajax. Presently what we are doing is

When we get the result from like `myresults`, we are passing to a function `populate` where we are building the result.

```
function populate(myresults)
{        
    var str='<table>';       
    for(var i in myresults){
        str+='<tr>';
        str+=myresults[i].name;
        str+='</tr>';    
    }
    str+='</table>';

    $('#divId').html(str);
}
```

Not exactly we are building tables in all places. The code is working perfectly, but I think writing of code like this is not the right approach. How can I can beautify my code.  I can use jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Can you use spaces between sentences (in addition to javascript and jquery)?

Comment: This isn't really a question and will probably be voted off.

Comment: A simple improvment would be to use a template engine, like handlebars. Or you can take it one step further, with knockoutjs, angularjs or similar.

Comment: Have you tried KnockoutJS for writing the templates and taking care of the binding?

Comment: Try using a templating engine like [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)

Comment: This question is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/
Short answer: escape data to avoid XSS, use a templating library.

Comment: how i can move from here

Comment: By the way you are closing `div` instead of `table`

Comment: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/B9W1wlgCF9WbbEFTxQrF?p=preview) using jsrender

Comment: @ArunPJohny i did not understand .Can u explain pls

Comment: @PSR one of the problem with your design is, if later you want to change the markup it becomes very difficult. If you use a template like jsrender then the view is separated from the data and is added as a markup in the html which can be easily modified. Then you can club both the template and data to create the desired markup

Comment: @ArunPJohny  how i can inplement jsrender in my application

Comment: shall we move to chat please

Comment: you have to include the library from https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender download the jsrender.js file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29108/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-psr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to look for TemplateEngine - it could allow to decrease code count and make it more clear.
[What Javascript Template Engines you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788611/what-javascript-template-engines-you-recommend)

Answer (score 1):

You should run your code through a linting engine like JSLint or JSHint and you should familiarize yourself with good practice.

Here's one way (of more than one possible solution) to optimize your code:

```
function populate(myresults) {
    var table = $(document.createElement('table'));       

    $(myresults).each(function (i) {
        var row = $(document.createElement('tr')),
            cell = $(document.createElement('td')).text(myresults[i].name);
        row.append(cell);
        table.append(row);
    });

    $('#divId').append(table);
}
```

Comment: `var table = $(document.createElement('table'));` there are some typos on the code... missing the `)` closing in the jquery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, creating a new DOM element more correct ?

Like this:

```
function populate(myresults)
  {        
   var str= $('<table />)';       
      for(var i in myresults){
        str.append($('<td />').text(myresults[i].name).appendTo($('<tr />')));
      }
    $('#divId').empty().append(str);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
function populate(myResults)
{        
    var tab = $('<table />');       
    for(var i in myResults){
      if (myResults.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          var tr = $('<tr />');
          tr.append($('<td /'>, {text: i.name}));
          tab.append(tr);
      }
    }
    $('#divId').append(tab);
}
```

Using a template engine as suggested by the others would be preferable as it's a better, more maintainable approach.