# I need to link to another HTML page inside my current HTML page using JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a web-page that has other pages nested inside of one main HTML file. So far, I have managed to get a working tab system in for its navigation menu, but instead of showing internal `<div>` content when a tab is selected, I want it to display another HTML page I have created.

I am trying to avoid using `<iframe>` if at all possible as I feel it wont be useful in the long-run. I have attempted to find an alternative, but I have been unable to so far.

> I am working with JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS- so I would appreciate help that includes these languages, *not* JQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: @GermanoPlebani That is a jquery solution, OP doesn't want that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames

Comment: _"I am trying to avoid using <iframe> if at all possible as I feel it wont be useful in the long-run"_ Why is that?

Comment: @j08691 because if I iframe a multiple level dropdown menu the dropdowns won't come out of the iframe as if when you use them outside a iframe

Comment: @AlbanLusitanae how do you know this is the case in OPs question? I think it would be better if OP answered this versus a guess.

Comment: @disinfor because he is mentioning navigation, and the problem with iframes in navigation and tabs, is that iframes' content cannot go out and overwrite other DIVs underneath it for instance, that is why I used a HTML+CSS3 and trying to call the code with a PHP Include

Comment: OP is talking about tab navigation to show content. _but instead of showing internal <div> content when a tab is selected, I want it to display another HTML page I have created._

Comment: @Gosi if you read the link inside you can find many answer not only with jquery

Comment: See also [Including external HTML file to another HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17148357/215552), [Include html in html through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17171916/215552), [How to include an HTML page into another HTML page without frame/iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676394/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for those links, they provide a lot of useful information that I required, and even answered a new question that I had just formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use *JQuery* or *iframes*, I suggest you use [html object tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp).

Create 2 `HTML` files. In my example, *one.html* and *two.html*

**one.html**

```
<div id="display"></div>

<script>
function load_anotherpage() {
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="two.html"></object>';
}

load_anotherpage();
</script>
```

**two.html**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: It seems as this was what I needed, Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is the desired solution because using an object tag to embed another html file has the same effect as using an iframe.

Comment: @NineBerry Is there another solution that does not include ```<iframe>``` or ```<object>``` that is also still using Javascript? I am open to multiple solutions that there may be in order to optimize my chances of finding the best fit.